# Automatic Roof Modelling on QGIS

Tags: qgis, modelling, cityengine

I have an area that I am modelling using QGIS, I have each building outline, and I extrude it via qgis2threejs. I wish to add another level of detail and model the roof of each house, which doesn't necessarily have to be accurate, but at least fit the building outline. Is there a way to achieve this, with roof elevation data and building outline(the polygon) without individually modelling 3d roofs for upwards of 60-100 different houses/buildings.

Comment: Have you already looked for solutions to these questions? Please do some research and tell us what you've already found.